# How can I append multiple texts to one dataframe (tibble) within a for loop using append function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple `*.txt` files that contain the title and texts that I want to process in R. A program below reads all the `*.txt` and displays the final file while skipping the first read texts.
My program is as here below. It uses for loop and I want to see all the texts

```
library(here)
library(glue)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

all_texts <- list.files(setwd('.KCI/'), (startsWith = 'abstract'))
for(i in seq(1:length(all_texts)))
{
    data <- read_tsv(all_texts[i], , show_col_types = FALSE)
    corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data[i]))
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], tolower)
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], removePunctuation)
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], removeNumbers)
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], stripWhitespace)
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], removeWords, c(stopwords("english"), mystopwords))
    corpus[i] <- tm_map(corpus[i], stemDocument)
    dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus[i])
  }
```

This program just reads the final document but skips the previous ones. Therefore I want even other documents to be displayed before the last one.

```
<Title>       <Year>        <Text>
How is it?     1998          I am wondering if it could end like that. Therefore the deal is too good to be true
```

Comment: It doesn't skip anything. Compare: `for(i in 1:10) {i}` and `for(i in 1:10) {print(i)}`. Try `print(dtm)` at the end of your loop.

Comment: I tried all the alternatives before writing such a loop but when I print, I just see the last line only. Not all the results like when your second option does after printing. If that is the case, can you help me with how to find the rowsum in decreasing order for words in every matrix from the formed dtm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a lot easier if you had provided some data.

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
##
#   two documents based on your example (t1 & t2 are identical here).
#
t1 <- read.delim(text='
                 Title\tYear\tText
                 How is it?\t1998\tI am wondering if it could end like that. Therefore the deal is too good to be true',
                 header=TRUE)
t2 <- read.delim(text='
                 Title\tYear\tText
                 How is it?\t1998\tI am wondering if it could end like that. Therefore the deal is too good to be true',
                 header=TRUE)
data <- list(t1,t2)   # listof documents
dtm.list <- lapply(data, function(x) {
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
  DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
})
lapply(dtm.list, inspect)
```

Note I left out `mystopwords` because you did not provide any.
In your case you could put the `read_tsv(...)` back into the function and use `lapply(...)` in the list of file names. Something like:

```
dtm.list <- lapply(all.texts, function(x) {
  data   <- read_tsv(x)
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data))
  ...
})
```

Where `...` are the lines of code in my example above.

If your ultimate goal is to analyze word frequency, you might be better off using `?termFreq`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it is excellent, however, the same implementation on my data gives wrong results.  When I inspect yours it gives `[[1]]` and `[[2]]` but mine gives `[[1]]` and the `[[2]]` because my two `*.txt*` files were read and presented in a data frame. could you advise the conversion from `dataframe` to `list`? I have tried to convert my 'dataframe` to be a `list` using the function `as.list` the output is  `List of 1` not 'List of 2` Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try the code snippet at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement it, the only thing I will extract from the data is `title` and `Text` but when I combine the bottom snippet and the upper one it gives a `tibble`, then it becomes difficult to establish the independent dtm's

Comment: Could you provide a couple of examples of your files? Say 3 or 4? Put them somewhere like Dropbox and provide a link.

Comment: Ooooh thank you so much for your concern, I finally made it... Thank you so much